# Creating a join condition using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application class and document class. I want to only display application that has a document

Application.java

```
 private int appId;

 private String lname;

 private String fname;

//getters setter generated
```

Document.java

```
private int appId;

private int docId;
//getters setters generated
```

I have not made any relation between Application and Document in the persistence class. I want to join them using criteria

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class, "application");

criteria.createAlias("Document.appId","app", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN,Restrictions.eqProperty("app", "application.appId"));
```

This is not giving any results. Do I need to make any changes in persistence class . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve what you want with criteria api, criteria api works with assocations, so in order to make your join you need mapped relations and not id. So why don't you just put entity relation instead of id ?

Comment: you can't make this possible because there is no relation between your application entity and document entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that without associations this cannot be achieved and here is how i made the association in Applicaition.java class

```
private int appId;

private String lname;

private String fname;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="appId", referencedColumnName="appId", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
Private Document document

//getters and setter generated
```